# Change calculation Based on select value dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a calculation app based on dropdown form values. I'd like to have the equation used changed based on what value is selected. The intake value works on submit, but exhaust does not.
The intake valve value is calculated based on this formula:

```
const calcIn = ((t + 1.54) * (v - 0.13));
```

The intake displays fine but when I switch the dropdown to exhaust the output value does not change.

```js
function calculateInt() {
  const v = document.getElementById('v').value;
  const t = document.getElementById('t').value;
  const form = document.getElementById('valves');
  const calcIn = ((t + 1.54) * (v - 0.13));
  const ans1 = Math.floor(calcIn);
  const calcEx = ((t + 1.69) * (v - 0.22));
  const ans2 = Math.floor(calcEx);

  if (form.value || 'intake') {
    document.getElementById('result').value = ans1;
  } else if (form.value || 'exhaust') {
    document.getElementById('result').value = ans2;
  } else {
    return 'No Inputs';
  }

};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
a,
p {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #010658;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffff;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #9B9B9D;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#vehicle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#vehicle {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#vehicle select {
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #010658;
}

#vehicle button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #010658;
  border-color: #010658;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#vehicle input {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #010658;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="calc.html">Calculator</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="container">
      <form id="vehicle">
        <div>
          <select name="vehicles" onchange="">
            <option value="14-Forester">2014 Forester</option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
          <select id="valves" name="valves">
            <option value="intake">Intake Valve</option>
            <option value="exhaust">Exhaust Valve</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Measured Clearance" id="v">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Current Shim" id="t">
        <button type="button" id="submit-btn" onclick="calculateInt();">Calculate</button>
        <input type="text" id="result">
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jq.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==`, not `||`, in your `if` statements:

```
if (form.value == 'intake') {
    document.getElementById('result').value = ans1;
} else if (form.value == 'exhaust') {
    document.getElementById('result').value = ans2;
}
```

Also, since there are only two options, you don't need the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so your calculations run fine on the first go. Now when you actually switch the input's value you have no code to "listen" for that. All you need to do is create an event listener that listens for the change in value in your input then call the calculateInt() function again.

so you have to create a var for  your form element and then add an on change event to the form that runs the calculateInt function everytime your select input values change.

ex.   form.addEventListener('onChange',calculateInt);

And make sure you check your conditionals in your if statement. you want to run an equality check  instead of an OR statement so use "==" or "===" (strict equality) instead of the "||"( OR) statement.

`code`
Sure no problem.

Outside of your calculateInt function you can place these two lines

**EDIT EXAMPLE BELOW**

`const form = document.getElementById('valves');
  form.addEventListener('change',calculateInt);`

Comment: Got it, do you have an example that you could show me?

Comment: Gave it a shot using the code you gave me but unfortunately it spits out the wrong value. EX: if I select the intake option and I use the values .22 and 256 it will give me 230 as the answer, With exhaust selected it only gives me a 2 digit value.

Comment: well it should give you 0 because your calculation for exhaust is 

  const calcEx = ((t + 1.69) * (v - 0.22));

0.22 - 0.22 = 0 and (256- 1.69) *  0 = 0

my solution only allows for your function to run when you change between the intake and exhaust select options.